# Possible bug with reputation display on Profile Page

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

I recently noticed a bug on the reputation displayed on my profile page.
It showed -14 and after three-four refreshes, changed back to the original (33 at that point)

This image shows **-14 reputation:-**
[image]

After couple of refreshes,
This image shows **33 reputation:-**
[image: Image with the original 33 reputation]

Comment: I have another bug to report. Not sure if I should post another question or report it here. I always see "2 badges" when viewing any other question but see "6 badges" when in profile

Comment: I can at least explain the badges thing: You have 2 badges on *Meta* StackOverflow, and 6 on StackOverflow

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Ok, cleared with that, Thanks

Comment: There is a tradition on StackOverflow. Whenever we add images we add a [freehand red circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) around the subject of interest (The reputation in this case). Do make the change of possible :D

Comment: I think I found the issue, you are on stackoverflooooooow and not stackoverflow

Comment: @BhargavRao Done! :D

Comment: @CRABOLO What you're seeing there is the new logo of Stack Overflow since it reached ten million questions. Notice the number of 'o's after the 'l'. It denotes the number 10,000,000.

[New Stack Overflow logo](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo-10m.svg)

Comment: @HareeshSivasubramanian: I think CRABOLO was just joking

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @Luke What is this supposed to mean

Comment: @Luke Yes but... reputation is *never* less than 1. Even if it were cached why would it display **-**14?